# Facebook comments plugin flashes then goes blank

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I was wondering if anyone else was having any issues with the facebook moderation tool or the comments plugin to be specific.

I just got this all set up and working this morning, but tonight the comments plugin loads, i see the comments for a split second and then the whole div goes blank...

Even when i check on the developer page to create code for the button, same thing, it flashes the comments and then goes blank. here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments

heres a simple page i made just to test.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>


<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
  <meta property="og:title" content="'.$title.'">
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.dudermang.com/test.php" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.dudermang.com/blog/logo.jpg" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="just a test" />
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="814183725332896" />
 



<title>testing</title>

<meta name="description" content="'testing shit'">

<meta name="author" content="CFaulk">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1">


</head>

<body><div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3&appId=814183725332896";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<h2>This is a test</h2>
<p>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.dudermang.com/test.php" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
</p><p>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.dudermang.com/test.php" data-version="v2.3"></div>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I cant seem to figure this out. am I doing something wrong or is FB experiencing an issue? I looked at another blogger that uses this and i can see the number of comments but the actual comments are gone so i assume this is just broken for everyone?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I just tried your code snippet on fbrell.com and it worked perfectly fine. Can you verify that you see the same behavior?

Comment: yes it started to work about 4 hours later that night. there must have been an issue with the facebook dashboard. thank you